# How can listen speed up/cancel event on transaction in my dapp?

Tags: web3js, metamask

i develop dapp using react and web3js.

i figure out that if user click speed up function or cancel in metamask, my dapp doesnt know event.

My dapp developed to track transaction hash user requested.

however, if user click speed up function or cancel in metamask, transaction hash which is user requested in my dapp will be disappeared.

i fail to track

alchemy say they can track replacement of transaction.

is there anyway i can track above event ?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @XaEk my dapp code is so big. let me know specific part you want to see !

Comment: that's ok! coudl you post your speedUp function?

Comment: @XaEk I am sorry for my late reply. speedUp function is a built-in feature in a meta-mask not in my dapp